# Extract an information with xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I've this xml's file.

```
<occupazione>
   <row>
      <cliente>aaa</cliente>
      <codicec>1</codicec>
      <numposto>85</numposto>
      <datainizio>02/04/2018</datainizio>
      <datafine>05/04/2018</datafine>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cliente>bbb</cliente>
      <codicec>2</codicec>
      <numposto>86</numposto>
      <datainizio>02/04/2018</datainizio>
      <datafine>05/04/2018</datafine>
   </row>
</occupazione>
```

Can I extract all  (one in this case) which have occupied numposto 85?

I tried to use the XPath-query:

```
/occupazione/row/numposto[.=85] | /occupazione/row/cliente
```

Comment: Yes you can, but what did you try yourself. Do you have some code of your own?

Comment: I tried this code
    /occupazione/row/numposto[.=85] | /occupazione/row/cliente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this XPath:

```
/occupazione/row[numposto = 85]
```